# Jquery tab navigation

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have created a row of tabbed links which when clicked move up to show that the tab has been selected. When another tab is clicked the current "up" tab returns to the "down" state and the new selected tab is changed to be "up".

It's a simple process, which works until the last tab is clicked, if you click off it doesn't return to the "down" position.

I have created a JS fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/MyPNz/1/

My Jquery is as follows:

```
$(function(){

$('a.tab-link-lower').click(function(){

     var index_highest = 0;

     // do this for each of the tabbed/folder links
     $("a.tab-link-lower").each(function(x){

          // remove any styling from all tabs when any tabbed folder is clicked               
          $('#tab'+x+'-lower a').css("color","#6c6a6a"); 
          $('#tab'+x+'-lower').css("font-weight","normal").css("border-bottom","0px").css("background-image","url(http://s23.postimg.org/aunz2qnmf/folder_tab2.png)").css("margin-top","2px");  

          $('#tab'+$(this).attr("id")).css("display","none");

     });

     // add button/link decoration for clicked tab folder when clicked
     $('#'+$(this).attr("id")+'-lower').css("font-weight","bold").css("background-image","url(http://s23.postimg.org/aunz2qnmf/folder_tab2_up.png)").css("color","#ff0000").css("font-size","11px").css("margin-top","-3px").css("border-bottom","1px solid #090");

     // change the color of the a:link once it has been clicked
     $('#tab'+$(this).attr("id")+' a').css("color","#000");

});
```

Thanks,

Alan.

Comment: Use my advice , do all css in css file , just use addClass,removeClass in jQuery , that will put your code in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that your element IDs are starting from 1 id="tab1-lower" and after that inside each() function you are using x parameter which is index starting from 0.
Just added extra variable called index which will be incremented x inside each() function

See fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/MyPNz/2/

```
     // do this for each of the tabbed/folder links
     $("a.tab-link-lower").each(function(x){
          var index = x + 1;
          // remove any styling from all tabs when any tabbed folder is clicked               
          $('#tab'+index+'-lower a').css("color","#6c6a6a"); 
          $('#tab'+index+'-lower').css("font-weight","normal").css("border-bottom","0px").css("background-image","url(http://s23.postimg.org/aunz2qnmf/folder_tab2.png)").css("margin-top","2px");  

          $('#tab'+$(this).attr("id")).css("display","none");

     });
```

Comment: @gregjar grrrr how annoying... thanks for pointing this out, it had  been troubling me all morning!

Answer (score 0):

I made a few updates.

- I removed the `.each` since you do not need to iterate over all of the elements in order to make the changes that are required.
- I updated the `.css` call to use an object as opposed to changing each css property individually.
- You do not need to use a variable in order to find the elements with `id`s. So I changed some lines of code to use the element that was clicked.

Here is the [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/MyPNz/6/).

And the jQuery

```
$(function(){

    $('a.tab-link-lower').click(function(){
         var $this = $(this),
             $tabs = $this.closest("div#tabs-row");        

             $tabs.find("div.tab-folder a").css("color", "#6c6a6a");
             $tabs.find("div.tab-folder").css({"font-weight": "normal", "border-bottom": "0px", "background-image": "url(http://s23.postimg.org/aunz2qnmf/folder_tab2.png)", "margin-top": "2px"});

             //$('#tab'+$(this).attr("id")).css("display","none");//this line is not doing anything since there are no matching elements

             $this.parent().css({"font-weight":"bold", "background-image":"url(http://s23.postimg.org/aunz2qnmf/folder_tab2_up.png)", "color":"#ff0000", "font-size":"11px", "margin-top":"-3px", "border-bottom":"1px solid #090"});
                     // change the color of the a:link once it has been clicked
             $this.css("color","#000");

        });
         });
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: excellent thanks i'll look over what you have changed for me and in future I will bear it in mind.